# error con pytesseract al cargar lenguajes

Tags: python, pytesseract, tesseract

estoy empezando a utilizar tesseract con python, y al intentar utilizar lenguajes me da error.

el codigo ejecutado es el siguiente:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'), lang='spa'))
```

el error es el siguiente:

```
raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/spa.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'spa\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pytesseract es un wrapper de Tesseract-OCR, por lo que tienes que revisar si la versión instalada de tesseract incluye el español (*spoiler alert: si te pide el archivo es porque no está incluido*). Para instalar un nuevo lenguaje en la versión 4.0.0 basta con descargar dicho archivo de https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata . Yo acabo de revisar y funciona en la version 5.0.0-alpha.20200328

Answer (score 0):

Tan solo debes descargar el modelo entrenado para detectar el idioma que desees de:

[Tesseract - Trained models](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata)

Después, debes poner este archivo dentro de carpeta tessdata donde está instalado Tesseract:

[image: Imagen]

Con esto y llamando al modelo por su nombre debería funcionar perfectamente.
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'), **lang='spa_best')**)